# Scraping Multiple Pages Using BeautifulSoup 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape multiple pages for specific links. For example, I want to be able to choose which link is followed with a specific amount of iterations. The result of the scrape from the initial input must be appended or replacewith the user input. I have:

```
#url = raw_input('Enter - ')
url = 'http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html'
itr = raw_input('Enter iteration: ')
i = int(itr)

n = raw_input('Enter Number: ')
n = int(n)

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')

print 'Link:' , url
while i > 0:
    i = i - 1
    if i == 0:
        break
    for tag in tags:  
        me = tag.get('href', None)
        #Just to make sure the link/content match print tag.contents[0]
        link = tags[(n - 1)]
        #print link 
    links = link.get('href', None)
    print 'Link:', links

Enter - http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/
Enter count: 4
Enter Position: 9
Link: http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/
Link: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html
Link: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html (Should be k95faq.html)
Link: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html (Should be ckfaq.html)
```

I'm getting the number of iterations I want, and the specific link, but I need the first url (the users input) to be replaced with the link under the variable "links" for each iteration.

Example would be for a user to input an url like http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/ with 4 iterations of the 9th link on the page. The first iteration would return http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html as "links". I want the second iteration to give me the 9th link on "links" which should be k95faq.html

Comment: Could you please insert an example situation into your post?

Comment: Yes @Koga this is a html page I found with various links. Let me know if the example is explicit enough to help.

Comment: it would be better to show it directly in your post

Comment: Done, although this website isn't the greatest example.

Comment: I figured it out, if anyone needs help with something similar, just write.